# Run a command with another egid (effective group id) without starting a new shell

Tags: linux

The following command starts `gedit` with the `group_a` `egid`:

```
sg group_a gedit
```

But apparently it starts the `sh` shell first.

Is there a way to run a command with another `egid` without starting a new shell?

Comment: What issue do you have with it running in child shell process?

Comment: @Kusalananda No particular issue, I just think it would be cleaner if the process was to run directly.